# designing Watch-face background

Tags: android, wear-os, watch, watch-face-api

I am new to designing android wear watch-faces. My question was if i only had to make the background image in GIMP or also the pointers and time markers? if so How can I best do this? Are there any tips I need to know?

Kind regards,
Emma

Answer (score 0):

Start here with the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html). The process is no different for wearables than regular mobile devices. You make the layouts in XML. These layouts can include layers of different image elements -- they could be png images that you create in Gimp, etc. Or they could be shape drawables that you also encode in XML.

Comment: this also works with watch_faces? I mean not like wearable apps. but the actual watch faces